# In NebulaGraph get subgraph statement, the vertex format must be tagName.propName

Tags: nebula-graph

Why in the get subgraph statement, I can't use the vertex in the format of tagName.propName like in the go statement.

```
(root@nebula) [subgraph]> GET SUBGRAPH 6 STEPS FROM "player101" WHERE $$.player.age>50 YIELD VERTICES AS nodes, EDGES AS relationships;
+---------------------------+---------------+
| nodes                     | relationships |
+---------------------------+---------------+
| [("player101" :player{})] | []            |
+---------------------------+---------------+
Got 1 rows (time spent 5803/7091 us)

Thu, 20 Oct 2022 03:45:11 UTC

(root@nebula) [subgraph]> GET SUBGRAPH 6 STEPS FROM "player101" WHERE player.age>50 YIELD VERTICES AS nodes, EDGES AS relationships;
[ERROR (-1005)]: EdgeName `player'  is nonexistent
```

```
(root@nebula) [subgraph]> GO FROM "player100" OVER follow WHERE follow.degree > 90  YIELD dst(edge);
+-----------+
| dst(EDGE) |
+-----------+
+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `GET SUBGRAPH` statement, you cannot use the vertex in the format of tagName.propName because the `WHERE` clause of the GET SUBGRAPH statement operates on the vertices and edges within the subgraph, rather than on the starting vertex or edge that you specify in the FROM clause.

Therefore, you should specify the vertex or edge properties directly in the `WHERE` clause using a reference symbol such as `&&`, rather than using the tagName.propName syntax.

To put it in a simple way, NebulaGraph does not support such a way of use.